# How to send html email sign up form to php that will auto-email me using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email

This html form gathers an email address. I would like that email address that the user provides to be auto-emailed to me. In the past, I've used PHP to do this no problem, but now I want the user to never have to leave the page and get a message confirming their submission... so I'd like to use ajax which I've never ever used.

```
<!-- Signup Form -->
        <form id="signup-form" method="post" action="">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <input type="submit" value="Make a Request" />
        </form>
```

This is the php file called "contact-form-handler.php" simplified and yes lacking in verification right now. (my bad)

```
<?php
$myemail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Someone visited RK" ;
$email_body = "You have received a new message. "
" Here are the details:"
"Email: $email_address";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers = "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
?>
```

Please note that this php is located in a different folder than my js when referring to its location. (file structure for each is: assets/php/contact-form-handler.php   and: assets/js/main.js)

Ok and finally the main.js file is from a template which is where my problem arises. It looks like this:
            // Signup Form.
            (function() {

```
        // Vars.
            var $form = document.querySelectorAll('#signup-form')[0],
                $submit = document.querySelectorAll('#signup-form input[type="submit"]')[0],
                $message;

        // Bail if addEventListener isn't supported.
            if (!('addEventListener' in $form))
                return;

        // Message.
            $message = document.createElement('span');
                $message.classList.add('message');
                $form.appendChild($message);

            $message._show = function(type, text) {

                $message.innerHTML = text;
                $message.classList.add(type);
                $message.classList.add('visible');

                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $message._hide();
                }, 3000);

            };

            $message._hide = function() {
                $message.classList.remove('visible');
            };

        // Events.
        // Note: If you're *not* using AJAX, get rid of this event listener.
             $form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();

                // Hide message.
                     $message._hide();

                // Disable submit.
                     $submit.disabled = true;

                // Process form.






                // Note: Doesn't actually do anything yet (other than report back with a "thank you"),
                // but there's enough here to piece together a working AJAX submission call that does.
                    window.setTimeout(function() {

                        // Reset form.
                            $form.reset();

                        // Enable submit.
                            $submit.disabled = false;

                        // Show message.
                            $message._show('success', 'Thank you! RK will be in touch with you soon.');
                            //$message._show('failure', 'Something went wrong. Please try again.');

                    }, 750);


            });

    })();

})();
```

I completely understand that there have been similar questions. I've been searching everywhere, but nothing is clear enough for a basic basic beginner. When answering, please explain every line of the ajax code so that I know what's going on. Thanks

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials for this. Google it, try it, and come back with a specific issue.

Comment: `"which is where my problem arises"` - What exactly is the problem?  Where is the code attempting to make an AJAX request to the server-side code?  Are you following some tutorial or example for AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#signup-form").submit(function(){
   var email_address = $("#email").val();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "contact-form-handler.php",
      data: {email:email};
      success: function(data) {
          $("#sameWhereDivID").text(data);
          //Please echo your message in your PHP file and use .text to print the successful or failure message in your page.
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: You should explain what your code does, even succinctly.